# Questions without a question mark (New Yorker)

Tags: punctuation, questions, auxiliary-verbs, titles, question-mark

1. *How to listen to music*
2. *How a City in France got out the World's first Short-Story vending machines*
3. *How we learn fairness*
4. *What makes great detective fiction according to T.S. Elliot*
5. *What went wrong at St Marks Bookshop*

I see that in the New Yorker we have these headlines. Even though they do not have question marks, are these questions? (Specially the first three examples)

Comment: No, they're not questions.  You could replace "how" with "the way" in the first 3 examples.

Comment: These may be considered as deletions of complement clauses (I know / Get to know how to listen to music), which do not take question marks.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth. Can you please elaborate on that? I mean, when I say "I know how to listen music" or "Get to know how to list to music" I believe these are indirect questions, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

How can be used in three contexts:
As an adverb: How do you make fish-and-chips?
As a conjunction: I know how this is done.
As a modifier to express surprise: How remarkable!

Comment: Are you saying that the three sentences are questions?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the how and why of there being only three contexts.

Comment: So "how"  in the post is used as a conjunction, akin to "Why to listen to music". But the construction is special: nothing is connected really, which would normally be what conjunctions do. Can you elaborate on that construction?

Comment: @Rathony. No, I am merely giving three examples of using how.

Comment: @deadrat. There could more than just  three contexts, I just provided three examples in this answer.

Comment: @Peter A. Schneider. I agree it is a little unusual but it could be understood as I know [and] how this is done.

Comment: The question is **are these questions?** Does your post answer the question?

Comment: @Rathony. Obviously, two of them are not. As I said before, I was just giving examples of the usage of how, and providing three instances.

Comment: You don't need to explain it to me. You could edit your post with an answer by clicking on **edit**.

Comment: As I know, there are two kinds of questions (direct and indirect questions). "I know how this is done" seems to me an indirect question. As Sydney Greenbaum's example: "They told me what the topic should be." Am I right?